# Looking for an example of a heuristic implementation in GAMS

Tags: mixed-integer-programming, solver, metaheuristics, heuristics, gams

I am new to GAMS and the documentation is not helping me to make fast progress.
I am looking for an example implementation similar to Relax and Fix heuristic
where in several iterations subsets of binary variables are relaxed/fixed.

Answer (score 5):

To fix a variable use `x.fx(i) = 1`. To unfix: `x.lo(i) = 0; x.up(i) = 1;`.

To relax an integer/binary variable you can use: `x.prior(i)=INF`;

Documentation of this can be found at the obvious place: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_Variables.html. [Here](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2008/06/rolling-horizon-implementation-in-gams.html) is an example of how to use this.

Comment: ty for the helpful comment. I saw u already hardcoded the subsets for the iterations, but i would prefer to do do this with a rolling-parameter and planning horizon width automatically. Any good advise there? I guess i have to read the whole documentation..

Comment: Sets can be dynamic. See the documentation.

Comment: i have my set of time..
##code##
Set
  t "Menge der Zeitperioden"  /T1  *  T20/
##code##
i an trying to get a subset lets say from T5 to T10. How is this done?

MY research: t_f(t)      = yes$(ord(t) le 4) ; ok it worked

Comment: Whats the difference when applying prior or lo and up to a binary?

Comment: Relaxing for `x.prior(i)` means: the variable is no longer binary but continuous. To relax bounds, use `x.lo(i)` and `x.up(i)`.

Comment: in the documentation it says: 
"Attention
Only execution statements are permitted in programming flow control statements. Consequently declaration statements and equation definitions are not allowed inside a loop statement.
It is illegal to modify any controlling set inside the body of the loop."

isn't changing values for variables a declaration?

Comment: `set i;` is a declaration and is handled at compile time. `j(i) = ord(i) < 4;` is **not** a declaration, and is handled at execution time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/116039/discussion-between-dereddie-and-erwin-kalvelagen).